# Unknown error in website admin panel

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I have the following problem in one of my websites backend:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2zcH.jpg)

[image]

The website was developed on a standart shared hosting and later was moved to a dedicated in-house server. The agency that developed the website said that I should enable *PHP short open tags*. I tried that via `.htaccess` and `php.ini` but it does not make any difference. It seems that the problem is somewhere else and I cannot identify what is causing this issues.

The server runs on [ispconfig](/questions/tagged/ispconfig), [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) and [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin).

Can anyone suggest why it is not working properly? Thank you!

Comment: Notice that you need to restart apache for the changes in your `php.ini` to take effect.

Comment: Did that as well...

Comment: You should also check you servers log files e.g `/var/log/apache2/error.log`